# Rating system giving wrong rating when clicked repeatedly

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have built a jquery-php based 5 star rating system.

Ratings are inserted/stored in database along with no of hits.

There is a some problem in inserting rating into database when any star is clicked repeatedly, i.e if a star is continuously clicked many times rating does not get inserted but hits get inserted which then effect the new resulting rating.

This is a php back-end issue, i tried to insert hits only when rating is inserted, but its not working.

PHP

```
    <?php 
    $post_rating = '5';
    $id = '1';
    $database = 'comment-database';
    $tablename = 'comment-table';
    require_once('rt-connect.php');

    $find_data = "SELECT hits, user_rating, rating_total FROM $tablename WHERE id='$id'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $find_data) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $current_hit = $row['hits'];
    $current_rating_total = $row['rating_total'];

    $new_hits = $current_hit+1;
    $new_rating_total = $current_rating_total + $post_rating;
    $new_rating = $new_rating_total / $new_hits;
    $new_round_rating = ceil($new_rating/0.5)*0.5;

    $update_rating = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE $tablename SET user_rating='$new_round_rating' WHERE id='$id'"); 
    if ($update_rating){
    $update_hits = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE $tablename SET hits='$new_hits' WHERE id='$id'");
    $update_rating_total = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE $tablename SET rating_total='$new_rating_total' WHERE id='$id'"); 
    }   

    $find_data2 = "SELECT hits, user_rating, raw_rating, rating_total FROM $tablename WHERE id='$id'";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($connection, $find_data2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);

    $current_hit2 = $row2['hits'];
    $current_rating2 = $row2['user_rating'];
    $current_raw_rating_total2 = $row2['raw_rating'];
    $current_rating_total2= $row2['rating_total'];

    echo $current_hit2.'<br />';
    echo $current_rating2.'<br />';
    echo $current_raw_rating_total2.'<br />';
    echo $current_rating_total2.'<br />';
    ?>
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: you have tagged this as jquery/html/ajax issue, yet I don't see any HTML provided. Could you provide that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are updating the same row (of the same table corresponding to the same id) for all the parameters, i.e. hits, rating, rating_total, why don't you just try doing it in a single update query. Then the transaction will be completely atomic and you don't have to worry abt one query passing and the other getting failed.

This should be your single update query:

```
UPDATE $tablename SET user_rating='$new_round_rating', hits='$new_hits',rating_total='$new_rating_total'   WHERE id='$id'
```

Do let us know if it works for you. This will not debug the actual issue but atleast be a cleaner implementation of the same.

Comment: Wow that was it, a singal query to update all, it's now working, thanks.